# Showing an Invalid Date, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the data does not exist in the database, there's no error but it will just display an Invalid Date on the screen. How can I do this where if the data does not exist in the database, then it will just be empty.

```
 First Item:
              {new Date(
                user.items?.firstDateseconds * 1000
              ).toDateString()}
```

Comment: you can write it like `user && user.items && user.items.firstDateseconds && {new Date(
                user.items?.firstDateseconds * 1000
              ).toDateString()} ` or if you want to place something special if there is not a date you can: `user && user.items && user.items.firstDateseconds ? new Date(
                user.items?.firstDateseconds * 1000
              ).toDateString() : 'there is no date' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **You could check if it's not empty before using `new Date()`**

**Something like this:**

```
First Item: {
   user.items?.firstDateseconds
      ? new Date(user.items.firstDateseconds * 1000).toDateString()
      : '';
}
```

Comment: Since you've already checked for null, you can omit the `?.` inside the `new Date(` expression.

Comment: @phuzi so it will be like this `new Date(user.items.firstDate.seconds * 1000).toDateString()` ?

Comment: `?` so he can put any string if the condition is false.

Comment: @RyanLe No, not talking about the ternary operator. I'm talking about the optional chaining operator `?.` in the term `user.items?.firstDateseconds` it is completely redundant and should be `new Date(user.items.firstDateseconds * 1000)`

Comment: Oh. I see, great point! I will update my answer. Thanks you